How to load local file urls of stored media in web view with flutter_inappwebview on iOS
I have html content as string with file urls embedded in media tags as shown below:
<p>Let's see if this works</p>
<p> <img src="file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A9C87532-47D9-4959-B2ED-E589AFF11F22/Documents/media/img1_1603362234.png" alt="" width="100%"> </img></p>
<p> Another image</p>
<p><img src="file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A9C87532-47D9-4959-B2ED-E589AFF11F22/Documents/media/img2_1603362234.jpeg" alt="" width="100%"></img>
</p>

I am using Flutter In App Web View version 6.0.0.
InAppWebView(key: GlobalKey(),
initialSettings: InAppWebViewSettings( allowFileAccessFromFileURLs: true, allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs: true, allowFileAccess: true, allowContentAccess: true ), initialData: InAppWebViewInitialData(data: loadHtmlFromAssets(content)), 
initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions( crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions( supportZoom: true, javaScriptEnabled: true, disableHorizontalScroll: true, disableVerticalScroll: false, allowFileAccessFromFileURLs: true, allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs: true 
),),);

When I run my flutter app and view the output on Android I am able to see the files stored on my internal storage rendered on the page however on iOS nothing renders. I added the options allowFileAccessFromFileURLs and allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs to try and achieve this but to no avail. Can anyone help me figure out why I cannot see them on iOS.
Flutter version: 3.16.8
iOS Version for test: 17
Info.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.transistorsoft.checkForUpdatesAndNotify</string>
        <string>com.transistorsoft.sendQueuedNetworkRequests</string>
        <string>com.transistorsoft.runQueuedNetworkRequests</string>
        <string>com.transistorsoft.fetch</string>
    </array>
    <key>CADisableMinimumFrameDurationOnPhone</key>
    <true/>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
    <array>
        <string>en</string>
        <string>fr</string>
        <string>es</string>
        <string>sw</string>
    </array>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Users may be able to submit files from their filesystem as a response to survey</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsIndirectInputEvents</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>processing</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>


